# Etymological origin of -n in 洗 (セン)

Tags: etymology, chinese

I've always wondered why the 音読み of the kanji 洗 is セン when, in all Chinese topolects I'm aware of, the reading ends in a vowel.

I always chalked this up to Japanese having borrowed a Middle Chinese reading at a time when 洗 still ended in a nasal (cf. the Japanese vs Chinese reading of 鳥), but I was surprised to find that this isn't the case, and that it's reconstructed as *sejX in Middle Chinese.

Why, then, is there a nasal in the Japanese reading (and according to Wiktionary, the Korean reading too)?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're referring to [the Baxter-Sagart Middle Chinese transcriptions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Baxter-Sagart_Old_Chinese_reconstruction) of the [Qieyun rime dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qieyun).    When I search these transcriptions for 洗, I find *two* readings listed:

1. *sejX, corresponding to modern Mandarin xǐ, Japanese セイ・サイ, and Korean 세 se
2. *senX, corresponding to modern Mandarin xiǎn, Japanese セン, and Korean 선 seon

So I think the final nasal already existed in Middle Chinese and was borrowed into Japanese.  This may not have been obvious because xǐ is the usual reading in modern Mandarin while セン is more common today in Japanese.

As for xiǎn, I don't know when this reading is used, but it *is* at least listed in my dictionary.  My Chinese is too rudimentary for me to say any more on the subject.    The Japanese and Mandarin readings listed above are from 新漢語林, and the Korean readings are taken from Wiktionary.

(For those who are curious, the final X in Baxter's notation indicates [a rising tone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baxter%27s_transcription_for_Middle_Chinese#Tones).)

Comment: Even more mysterious is 向 (whose on'yomi is こう). [Baxter-Sagart](http://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%90%91#.E6.B1.89.E8.AF.AD) doesn't even have anything that sound like it.

Comment: @3to5businessdays What's so strange about that? /xjangH/ has an /x/ initial, which in Japanese appears regularly as /k/, and /ang/ appears regularly as /oː/ (via /au/).

Comment: Even if it does appear regularly, to me /x/->/k/, /ang/->/oː/ is pretty strange because they don't sound alike. Do you know if it's taken from some kind of dialect or are there any reason for such a change in sound?

Comment: @3to5businessdays - those are just the regular results of Japanese's borrowing strategies. Japanese didn't have /x/ or /ŋ/, and so it borrowed those as /k/ and /u/ (which were the closest it had) - so *xjangH became /kau/. /au/ later became /oo/, giving /koo/.

Comment: (And don't be misled by /h/ in modern Japanese – at the time Chinese words were being borrowed, it was a labial sound like [p] or [f].)

Comment: @3to5businessdays, Middle Chinese /x/ evolved into an /h/ in some dialects, suggesting that a hard /h/ like the [ch] in Scottish _loch_ was a possible realization of this sound.  Hard /h/ to /k/ is a closer phonetic shift than starting from the slightly-affricated apical sibilant /x/ as realized in modern Mandarin.

Comment: 洗 _Xiǎn_ is a surname in China (not a common one, but it does exist). It’s apparently also used in the word 洗馬/洗马 _xiǎnmǎ_ ‘official title given to the crown prince's herald’ (WTF?). A minor point: the Baxter-Sagart reconstruction is for _Old_ Chinese. The Middle Chinese reconstructions were made by various other scholars (only Karlgren and Wang Li happen to disagree on this one, having _\*siei ~ \*sien_ instead of _\*sei ~ \*sen_). The odd thing about this one is that if you look at the Baxter-Sagart OC reconstructions, they’re the same for both MC forms: _\*sˤərʔ_. I’m not quite up to →

Comment: → scratch on my OC reconstructions, but I don’t _think_ a final /r(ʔ)/ becoming MC /n/ is by any means regular; /j/ would be the regular outcome (as found in _*sej_). Then again, B-S also have _*sˤər_ as the OC reconstruction for 先, which is always _xiān_ in Mandarin, with the nasal. So yes, the /n/-final version definitely seems to have existed in MC, but how it arose is less obvious.

Comment: @Eiríkr Middle Chinese /x/ here is an IPA /x/, not a Pinyin /x/. In other words, the /x/ in the Middle-Chinese reconstruction /xjang/ **is** the ‘hard h’ sound found in Scottish _loch_ /lɒx/ which has remained in some dialects (like Mandarin) and has become /h/ in others (like Cantonese). In Middle Chinese, it was still /x/ throughout, though, and it was quite regularly represented in Japanese by /k/. The sound denoted by ⟨x⟩ in Pinyin is /ɕ/, which is the result of a much _later_ palatalisation of /x/ (and /s/ and /ʂ/) before front vowels, which is why /xjaŋ/ is now /ɕaŋ/, but Pinyin ⟨xiàng⟩.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, derp, thank you for rectifying my confusion.  That said, http://www.chinalanguage.com/dictionaries/?dict=oldchinese&mode=view&query=%E5%90%91 shows that other reconstructions of Middle Chinese 向 include `/ç/`, `/ɕ/`, `/h/`, and `/s/`, as well as `/x/`.  I'm not up on the details here enough though to tell if this variation might suggest geographic or dialectal differences, but it seems the palatalization might have been earlier.

Comment: @Eiríkr Those are for two different pronunciations. 向 in Mandarin can be both _xiàng_ (plus _xiǎng_) and _shǎng_, and the versions with initial /s/ and /ç ~ ɕ/ are the ones that give modern /ʂ/, as in _shǎng_. This pronunciation is almost never written as 向 anymore, though—it’s been replaced with 晌, which only has this pronunciation. I believe some scholars simply reconstruct /h/ without really determining whether it was /x/ or /h/ specifically at the time—but /x/ makes most sense considering Japanese. /x/ → /h + k/ is easier to explain than /h/ → /x + k/.

Comment: By the way, the Middle Chinese transcriptions I referenced (Baxter & Sagart's – they don't appear to credit anyone else for them) are specifically not intended as reconstructions.  I'm a little confused by the comments above, possibly because I'm not familiar with the MC reconstructions that are out there, but you can read about B&S's MC transcriptions in B&S 2014 around page 12.

Comment: @snailboat Ah, I see. I don’t actually have the book and hadn’t read it before (just read through the relevant pages on Google Books now), so I thought they were just referencing established MC reconstructions, since both forms here happen to coincide exactly with the most commonly reconstructed forms. B-S are well-known for their OC reconstructions, but I wasn’t aware they’d really done anything about MC (which, I suppose, they _haven’t_, since they emphasise that they’re _not_ reconstructing).

Answer (score 2):

According to Pulleyblank's Lexicon of Reconstructed Pronunciation (http://books.google.com/books?id=qWGIxP1R4P4C, p336), there's a reconstructed EMC pronunciation of 洗 as *sɛn' (no idea what the apostrophe means, though - glottal stop?). This apparently corresponds to a modern Mandarin pronunciation of xiǎn, which also has a nasal final.

There may also be a reconstructed pronunciation of 洗 corresponding to modern Mandarin xǐ (the other option a lookup gives, and the pronunciation I assume you're referring to), but Google Books won't give me the page it should be on. If anyone has that book (or Google Books does give you that page), look it up somewhere on pages 330-332 and let me know if it's there.